# Rectangles strips after scrolling in Java

Tags: java, swing, scroll, awt, paintcomponent

I use Netbeans8 and Java7. Inside a `JPanel` embedded in a `JScrollPane` I draw a lot of coloured rectangles. When I scroll down via the scroll bar some of the rectangles are shown in strange strips, as illustrated in the following image (specifically, see the blue rectangle).

[image: An example of the strips]

I paint rectangles as follows in the class that extends `JPanel`.

```
List<Rectangle> rectagles = ...
List<Color> colours = ...

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    int index = 0;
    int maxX = 0;
    int maxY = 0;
    for (Rectangle r : rectangles) {
        g.setColor(colours.get(index));
        int x = r.x;
        int y = r.y;
        int width = r.width;
        int height = r.height;

        maxX = Math.max(maxX, x + width);
        maxY = Math.max(maxY, y + height);

        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
        index++;
    }
    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(maxX, maxY));
    this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(maxX, maxY));
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(maxX, maxY));
}
```

How can I prevent this annoying situation?

Comment: Are you clearing your screen anywhere in your code after each draw? If not, drawing on top of what was there previously can often have an effect like this.

Comment: The code actually only create a `JInternalFrame` in my `JFrame`. The `JInternalFrame` contains the `JScrollPane` and the `JPanel`. The `paint` method of the class extending `JPanel` is called via the constructor and the list of `Rectangle` objects is initialized in a static block. So, I don't call any additional `draw` method! What should I do exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

at the top of your paintComponent() method to clear the background before you do your custom painting.